# how to make getElementsByClassName work

Tags: javascript

I been reading about getElmentByClassName but I cant seem to get it work in any browser, 
The function i have works when o call the ID name, but i would like to be able to call the classname.

Is there any way that don't include Jquery ?

This is what I have, would be awsome with some help.
thanks.

```
<ul><li><button class="testButton">Test button</button></li></ul>

function OnButtonDown (button) {
alert("The class work")
}

function Init () {
    var className = "testButton";
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    if (button.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
        button.addEventListener ("mousedown", function () {
            OnButtonDown (button)
            }, false);
        button.addEventListener ("mouseup", function () {
            OnButtonUp (button)
            }, false);
    }
    else {
        if (button.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
            button.attachEvent ("onmousedown", function () {
                OnButtonDown (button)
                });
            button.attachEvent ("onmouseup", function () {
                OnButtonUp (button)
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debugging tip: `console.log( button );`

Comment: @linski how is he supposed to make a short "compilable" example out of a piece of code from a website ...? He already posted enough code to make a clear point of what his problem is and how to solve it. If you dont know the answer then you dont understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of HTML elements, you need to access the elements of the collection using their index:

```
button = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
// your code here
```

If you have only one element, please consider to use `.getElementById()`.

Comment: It is getElementsByClassName, not getElementByClassName. I cant suggest edit because it is only one char :)

Comment: thanks :P it's my habbit to use `.getElementById()`

Comment: what what! I didn't know that it returns collection of HTML elements.
Well now its works! thank you really really much!

Comment: @micnic, Yeah actually this happen to every developer. Some times I remember this little annoying 's' after two hours of debugging!!

Comment: @micnic Another question that I have. Is there a way to see class index ? the thing is that every class I have is generated by Js.

I could count them by hand, but that's not the point :)

Comment: what do you mean by class index? the index of the class name in the class attribute or the number of elements with this class or something else?

Answer (score 2):

What @micnic said.

FYI. In the case that `document.getElementById()` *doesn't* work for you, here's how you would handle it:

```
var button = false;
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    button = buttons[i];
    // do stuff with button
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3pAeM/

Comment: This function was actually easier this I didn't have to use the index:)
Thanks